# How can I show the author's latest post with title?

Tags: get-posts, list, list-authors, translation

The following is my code: (klcom is my theme name)

I just show the author by: name and description, I want to show the author's last 3 post with tile after each author, How can I code?

Thanks

```php
<ul class="klcom-user-list user-cols-<?php echo $cols;?>">
    <?php foreach ( $users as $user ){
        $cover_photo = klcom_get_cover_url( $user->ID );
        $group = klcom_get_user_group( $user->ID ); ?>
        <li class="klcom-user-item">
            <div class="klcom-user-cover"><?php echo klcom_lazyimg($cover_photo, $user->display_name);?></div>
            <div class="klcom-user-avatar">
                <a class="avatar-link" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID );?>" target="_blank">
                    <?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 120, '', $user->display_name );?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="klcom-user-name">
                <p>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID );?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $user->display_name;?></a>
                    <?php if($group){ ?><span class="wpcom-user-group"><?php echo $group->name;?></span><?php } ?>
                    <p class="author-description"> <? echo $user->description; ?></p>
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 2):

As you already have the author's ID, you can create a new WP_Query and get the 3 latest posts of the Author.

The following code will do the job for you,

```
$getPosts = new WP_Query(
    array(
        "author"         => $user->ID, // This tells the query which author's post you want to get.
        "posts_per_page" => 3,         // This tells the query how many posts you want. In your case, 3.
        "orderby"        => date,      // This tells the query that you want the posts according to their publish date.
        "order"          => "DESC",    // This tells the query that you want to get the latest posts. If you change it to "ASC", then the query will get the oldest posts.
    )
);
if($getPosts->have_posts()) {
    while($getPosts->have_posts()) {
        $getPosts->the_post();
        echo "<h2 class=\"post-title\"><a href=\"" . get_the_permalink() . "\">" . get_the_title() . "</a></h2>"; // Echo the post title as a link to the post on the page.
    }
}
```